# Automapper - AssertConfigurationIsValid call fails but mapping still works

Tags: c#, automapper

Not sure if this is a bug or I'm not using it right, but seems like Automapper can map properties even though `AssertConfigurationIsValid` fails. In the following tests, `ShouldMapSourceList` will pass even though `AssertConfigurationIsValid` fails in `ShouldValidateAgainstSourceListOnly`:

```
using AutoMapper;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace AutoMapperTests
{


    [TestClass]
    public class CreateMapTests
    {
        private class A
        {
            public string PropID { get; set; }
            public string PropB { get; set; }
        }

        private class B
        {
            public string PropId { get; set; }
            public string PropB { get; set; }
            public string PropC { get; set; }
        }

        internal class CreateMapTestProfile : Profile
        {
            protected override void Configure()
            {
                // will complain about Unmapped member PropC when AssertConfigurationIsValid is called.
                CreateMap<A, B>();
            }
        }

        internal class CreateMapTestWithSourceMemberListProfile : Profile
        {
            protected override void Configure()
            {
                // will complain about Unmapped member PropID when AssertConfigurationIsValid is called.
                CreateMap<A, B>(MemberList.Source);

            }
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void ShouldMapSourceList()
        {
            Mapper.AddProfile<CreateMapTestWithSourceMemberListProfile>();
            //Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

            var a = new A
            {
                PropID = "someId",
                PropB = "random",
            };

            var actual = Mapper.Map<B>(a);

            Assert.AreEqual("someId", actual.PropId);

        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void ShouldValidateAgainstSourceListOnly()
        {
            Mapper.AddProfile<CreateMapTestWithSourceMemberListProfile>();
            Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

            // if we got here without exceptions, it means we're good!
            Assert.IsTrue(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Shouldn't the mapping fail if configuration is not valid? Or if the configuration is valid, why does `AssertConfigurationIsValid` fail?

Test project here: https://github.com/mrchief/AutoMapperTests/blob/master/CreateMapTests.cs

Comment: What is `MemberList.Source`?

Comment: One of the enums you can pass to `CreateMap`. Essentially it tells Automapper to check that all source members are mapped. Default is `MemberList.Destination`.

Comment: My understanding of `AssertConfigurationIsValid` is that it checks for  missing members on destination types. This is not the same as not being able to map the two types at all. AutoMapper will still try to map the types at runtime to each other the best it can. In other words, just because `AssertConfigurationIsValid` fails, that doesn't mean AutoMapper won't be able to map the types.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker: In that case, shouldn't passing `MemberList.Source` make it valid, since all source members are mapped?

Comment: @Mrchief: Ah ok, sorry, I missed that detail. I haven't actually used `MemberList.Source` before.

Answer (score 4):

Configuration validation is about making sure that you don't mispell something in your destination type. Since AutoMapper is inferring what you're trying to map, the test is about validating that assertion. The map can still work of course, but you might assume a destination property is going to be mapped when in reality there is no matching member.

The MemberList enum is about what list of members to validate. By default it's the destination type but in some cases we actually want to use the source type as the list of members to check against.